# In what sense is momentum "optimal" for optimisation of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent

[This article](https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/) states about the use of momentum in gradient descent for neural networks:

> A lower bound, courtesy of Nesterov [[5]](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-8853-9), states that momentum is, in a certain very narrow and technical sense, optimal.

I cannot open the Nesterov reference, since it is a book (and probably I'd find it hard to understand anyway).

Could you explain in what sense momentum is optimal for optimization?

Comment: The article you referenced is a great article from a really cool site.